# How to properly call a sub by referencing in Perl

Tags: perl, reference

I'm working on a dispatching script. It takes a string with a command, does some cooking to it, and then parses it. But I can't grab a hold into the referencing:

```
Use::strict;
Use:warnings;

my($contexto, $cmd, $target, $ultpos, @params);
my $do = "echo5 sample string that says stuff ";

$target = "";
$cmd = "";
$_ = "";
# I do some cumbersome string parsing to get the array with
# the exploded string and then call parsear(@command)

sub parsear {

   my %operations = (
       'echo'   => \&echo,
       'status' => \&status,
       'echo5'  => \&echo5,
   );

   my $op = $_[0];
   if ($operations{$op}){
       $operations{$op}->(@_);
       print "it exists\n";
   }
   else{
       print "incorrect command.\n";
   }
}


sub status {
    print "correct status.\n";
}

sub echo {
    shift(@_);
    print join(' ',@_) . "\n";
}

sub echo5 {
    shift(@_);
    print join(' ',@_) . "\n" x 5;
}
```

I don't really know what the problem is. If the *sub* does not exist, it never says "incorrect command", and if I call for example "echo5 hello" it should print out:

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

But it does nothing.

And when I call *echo*, it works as expected. What is the explanation?

Note: I'm on the latest version of [Strawberry Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;  # 'use' is a keyword
use warnings;

# All these variables are not needed

sub parsear {  # Learn to indent correctly
    my %operations = (
        'echo'   => \&echo,
        'status' => \&status,
        'echo5'  => \&echo5,
    );
    my $op = shift;  # take first element off @_
    if ($operations{$op}) {
        print "$op exists\n";  # Make your status message useful
        $operations{$op}->(@_);
    } else {
        print "incorrect command: $op\n";  # And your error message
    }
}

sub status {
    print "correct status.\n";
}

sub echo {
    # shift(@_); # This is no longer needed, and now echo can be used as a
                 # normal subroutine as well as a dispatch target
    print join(' ',@_) . "\n";
}

sub echo5 {
    # shift(@_); # This is no longer needed
    print +(join(' ',@_) . "\n") x 5;  # Parentheses are needed since x binds tightly
}
```

Then running:

```
parsear 'status';
parsear 'echo', 'hello';
parsear 'echo5', 'hello';
parsear 'an error';
```

results in:

```
status exists
correct status.
echo exists
hello
echo5 exists
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
incorrect command: an error
```

I am not sure what *"cumbersome string parsing"* you are doing since you did not include it, but if you are parsing a string like

```
my $do = "echo5 sample string that says stuff ";
```

where the command is the first word, and the arguments are the rest, you can either split everything:

```
parsear split /\s+/, $do;
```

Or use a regex to cut the first word off:

```
my ($cmd, $arg) = $do =~ /^(\w+)\s*(.*)/;

parsear $cmd => $arg;
```

You don’t even need the variables:

```
parsear $do =~ /^(\w+)\s*(.*)/;
```

---

Finally, the `echo5` subroutine is a bit more complicated than it needs to be. It could be written as:

```
sub echo5 {
    print "@_\n" x 5;  # "@_" means join($", @_) and $" defaults to ' '
}
```

Comment: +1: However, the `shift` operations now documented as `# this should not be here` were needed in the original code because the original does not have the `my $op = shift;` that your code does.  You're right that they are not needed with the `shift` in `parsear`; but they were needed in the original.

Comment: You can also use split rather than a regex to "cut the first word off": my($cmd, $arg) = split /\s+/, $do, 2;

Answer (score 0):

The `x` command binds differently from how you were expecting; you probably wanted:

```
print ((join(' ', @_) . "\n") x 5);
```

Both extra sets of parentheses seemed to be necessary.